# How can I skip the intro videos on Master of Orion (2016)?

Tags: master-of-orion-2016

There are a bunch of brief - but unskippable - movies playing when I launch Master of Orion. Is there some way to skip those, preferably permanently?

Comment: As I haven't played the game yet, I won't give an answer; but in most games video files work the same view, so I'll give this general suggestion. Video files should be available in the game directory. Look for a video directory in the game folger. In genreal intro-videos are called intro.bik and logo.bik or something similar. Deleting those shouldn't create any problems, they will simply be skipped and you get the main menu.

Comment: @Dulkan renaming them is safer. . .

Comment: @Namikaze Technically yes, but practically it doesn't make much of a difference. Whether you rename them back or get them out of the recycle bin, if something doesn't work, doesn't matter. If the game really wants them, they'll be redownloaded anyway(on steam or gog galaxy at least). And I've never experienced a patch so far, which refuses to work because video files are missing. Then again, the small amount of storage space you waste on keeping them doesn't matter as well.

Comment: It might be better to replace them with a zero length blank video instead of just deleting them. Less room for unexpected behavior.

Comment: ahaha . .. i always use shift+del when deleting small file, so i assume other do that too.

Comment: @Fambida Yep, that's the best way. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @Dulkan there are no bik files, nor any other obvious stand-alone video files, in the game folder.

Comment: @Oak Are the game files all packed in some big archive? I.e. is there a single file, which is almost as big as the entire folder?

Comment: @Dulkan there are loads of small files and a few GB-sized files.

Comment: @Oak Then it's likely the video files are contained within the GB-files(archives). If you can open them with a standard packing tool, you can access them fairly easily. If not, you require a tool to access archives of that type. Replacing/Deleting them within the archive works the same, if you can simply open it. If you are forced to unpack and repack, then the required effort is considerably higher. This is a somewhat more risky operation, so I'd recommend making a backup before attempting. If you are unable to access the archives, you will have to wait for a mod.

Answer (score 3):

To skip the intro movies, edit the file "sharedassets0.assets" with a HEX editor and search for the 1st occurrence of "DURATION=8.00" (mine is at 0x667C81), change it to "DURATION=0.00".
Next, search for the 1st occurrence of "DURATION=62.68" (mine is at 0x9058CC), change it to "DURATION=00.00" and save the file.

This will disable the WG LABS video and the introduction cinematic, but I couldn't find a way to get rid of the NGD logo, if anyone knows, please share.

HTH,
Og